# How to remove hashtag from URL with multiple sub links in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am using AngularJS in a new project and I'm trying to remove the `#` from the URL.  I used `$locationProvider.html5Mode` and set fallback in my Gulp file.  It got rid of all `#` in my code.

I noticed that it only works with `/example` links.
`/example1/example2` are blocking the browser and not working properly.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Fixed grammar and formatting